# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC …… の部分の意味は何ですか？

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>サンプル</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
print 'Hello Word';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

これの最初に書いてある

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
```

は何のためにあるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

この文書がどういうバージョンの HTML / XHTML なのかを指定し、更に、文書がどういう自然言語で書かれているかなどの細かい指定を行っています。具体的に言うと、

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

は、XHTML 1.0 Transitional のための [DOCTYPE 宣言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E6%9B%B8%E5%9E%8B%E5%AE%A3%E8%A8%80)です。また、

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ja" lang="ja">
```

は、この文書の [XML 名前空間](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Markup_Language#XML.E5.90.8D.E5.89.8D.E7.A9.BA.E9.96.93)と、文書を記述している自然言語の指定を行っています。日本語の XHTML 文書を書く場合、html タグ中のこの指定は標準的だと思います。

#### 参考

- 公式

  - ["Recommended Doctype Declarations to use in your Web document."](https://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) -- W3C QA
  - ["Namespaces in XML 1.0"](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/) -- W3C
- 非公式

  - [XHTMLの書き方と留意点](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/html/xhtml1.html) -- The Web KANZAKI
  - [XML名前空間の簡単な説明](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/sw/names.html) -- The Web KANZAKI
  - [XML名前空間](http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/aig/01xml/namespace.html) -- @IT XML用語辞典
  - [xmlns属性](http://w-d-l.net/html__tips__xmlns/) -- Web Design Lesson